# Differentiation mapping: proving the mapping is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> **Exercise.**
>
> Suppose $D \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ is such that
> $\text{deg }Dp = (\text{deg }p) - 1$ for every non-constant polynomial
> $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that $D$ is surjective.

*Note on notation: $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ represents the set of all linear transformations from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all polynomials defined over the set of real numbers. Also, $\text{deg }p$ represents the degree of a polynomial $p$.*

**What I've tried.**

We see that $D$ is the differentiation map defined by $Dp = p'$. We need to show $\text{range }D = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$; we already know that $\text{range }D \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ by the following: [image]

We now show $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \text{range }D$. Consider a $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$
p(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x^1 + a_0x^0
$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This implies $\text{deg }p = n$, where $n$ is arbitrary and ranges from $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$

Consider a $q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$
q(x) = na_nx^{n-1} + (n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2} + \cdots + 2a_2x^1 + a_1x^0
$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We know such a $q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ exists since $$na_nx^{n-1}, (n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}, \ldots, 2a_2x^1, a_1x^0 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$$ where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space, implying it is closed under addition.

Notice that $Dp = q$. With $Dp \in \text{range }D$ and $Dp = q$, we must have $q \in \text{range }D$.

Since $q$ is defined by any choice of $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, we have that $q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ represents every polynomial in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. Thus, our showing of $ q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \implies q \in \text{range }D$ implies that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \text{range }D$.

With $\text{range }D \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \text{range }D$, we have $\text{range }D = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, implying that $D$ is surjective.

**Questions.**

1. Have I really shown that my definition of $q$ represents every polynomial in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?
2. If to the above question the answer is "No", do I need to show that any $q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $Dp$'s in $\text{range }D$? Or instead, would I just need to use induction on $q$ somehow?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak I added a note on the notation above.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak, sorry, just added that in too.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak because it's given $\text{deg } Dp = (\text{deg }p) -1$.  We can show that this implies $Dp = p'$, and vice versa, right?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak ah shoot, I see. That mapping is a counter example to the implication. Thank you, I will try to approach this question differently then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of $\mathcal D$ we know that:

$$D x^n = a_{n, n} x^{n-1}+ ... + a_{n,1}x^0.$$

Since $\deg D x^n = n-1$ we have that $a_{n,n}\neq 0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

This gives a system of linear equations with an infinite number of equations. Consider the first $k\geq 1$ equations. This system of linear equations is given by a triangular matrix $A$:

$$A_{ij} = \begin{cases}a_{i,j}&j\leq i\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Please note that this yields as $k$ equations in $k$ unknowns. Note further that we omit the equation $D 1 = 0$. Our matrix $A$ will map the span of $x, ..., x^n$ to the span of $x^0, ..., x^{n-1}$. So if we want to find a polynomial $p$ such that $Dp = x^i$, we need to invert $D$. In terms of our linear equations that means, we need to invert $A$.

$A$ is invertible however, since $a_{i,i}$ needs to be non zero for the degree condition to hold. So we can always find a polynomial $p_i$ of degree $i+1$ such that $Dp = x^i$, proving surjectivity on the spans. Since we haven't put any limit on $k$ or arguing by induction, we can remove the limit of $k$.